# How to Launch any iPhone application from terminal when usb connected?

Tags: iphone, terminal, launch

In a situation i am stuck to part where i need to launch any iPhone application from terminal . Obvious that it is USB connected . Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: You need to show us what you've implementeed

Comment: @Sidsec9 i have implemented nothing but i want to launch any app from Terminal . I don't want jail break .

Answer (score 7):

I myself got an answer to my question by investing lot of time.

First fetch Identifier

```
ideviceinstaller -l
```

Second copy the Identifier of the app which you want to launch

```
idevicedebug run " App Identifier "
```

That's it here you go .